# using jquery, How to redirect when drop down list selection changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list, if someone selects an option I want to redirect to another page based on the selection.

How can I do this via jquery?

Answer (score 21):

Bind the logic to the `$.change()` event, and get the current value from `$.val()` to determine where the user ought to be redirected to. This example assumes a location is stored directly in the value itself.

```
$(".mySelect").change(function(e){
  window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<select id="abc">
    <option value="p1">Page 1</option>
    <option value="p2">Page 2</option>
    <option value="p3">Page 3</option>
</select>

$("#abc").change(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://domain/" + $(this).val() + ".html";
});
```