# button on click get select value and do something

Tags: jquery, html

```
  <div class="selCont">
        <h2>pick an option</h2>
        <select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1">West</option>
            <option value="2">Land</option>
            <option value="3">Easter</option>
            <option value="4">Springtime</option>
            <option value="5">Celtic</option>
            <option value="6">Spectacular/</option>
            <option value="7">Weekend</option>
            <option value="8">Dark</option>
            <option value="9">Treasures</option>
        </select>
        <button class="go-btn" type="submit">
        Go
        </button>
</div>
```

So basically i want to be able for a user to select an option, and upon hitting the go button, for a script to run and look at the value of the dropdown and use the value to send them to the relevant page.

I've been trying a few things but as of yet it's not hanging together too well. Any help appreciated as always.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/TmfyC/ - Here is what is what ive tried most recently with the help from one of the comments.

****WHAT I USED FOR PEOPLE WHO IT MIGHT BENEFIT****

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    window.location = $('#my-dropdown').val();
});
```

This is what i ended up doing, i then assigned the value as the url of my pages. Seems to work like a treat. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2 things : http://jsfiddle.net/xSyF2/1/ **OR** http://jsfiddle.net/xSyF2/

**code**

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected');
    alert(" If you want text ==>"  + selected.html()); 
});​
```

**OR**

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    alert(" If you just want value ==>"  + $('#my-dropdown').val()); 
});​
```

Comment: @Raminson brooooooo Wat up man! hows things hard to meet you , thecodeplex and gdoron these days here `:)` time for me to dose off soon `B-)`

Comment: this is brill, thanks mate. How would i handle send the user to the various pages efficiently?

Comment: No worries bruv! +1 for your question as I reckon it do-not deserve down vote `:)` how do you mean you mean redirect to a page?

Comment: so there's like 8 options, each a separate page that the user is choosing to view. So is there a good way to handle this without masses of code? + thanks man

Comment: @Mat-visual cooloeos 2 options if I get you right: **1)** look in here (redirect based on selected option): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421335/using-jquery-how-to-redirect-when-drop-down-list-selection-changes  **2)** If the pages are mere `divs` the you can use `.show` and `hide` apis. I reckon if its totally new question spend some time and think it through and might ask with clarity as you get a good place to start from this question and answers anyways `:)` rest feel free to post if it helped innit `:P`

Comment: I'm here BRO :), hard to meet you!? lol, who is  _thecodeplex_? :)

Comment: Lol @Raminson yeah trying to take time off SO these days `:)` another oldie in the block when I joined 4 and half months back bruv!

Comment: @Tats_innit Me too Bro, I'm developing ma own website, _phew_.

Comment: Thanks @Tats_innit - I found the same thing :)

Comment: @Mat-visual Ah cool `:)` Glad it helped bruv! have a nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick example of a way to do it using normal javascript, not jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function goToProperPage() {
        var url;
        var location = document.getElementById("my-dropdown").selectedIndex;
        if (location == 1) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/west';
        }
        else if (location == 2) {
            url = 'http://www.page.com/land';
        }
        window.location.href=url;
    }

</script>

<div class="selCont">
    <h2>pick an option</h2>
    <select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">West</option>
        <option value="2">Land</option>
        <option value="3">Easter</option>
        <option value="4">Springtime</option>
        <option value="5">Celtic</option>
        <option value="6">Spectacular/</option>
        <option value="7">Weekend</option>
        <option value="8">Dark</option>
        <option value="9">Treasures</option>
    </select>
    <button class="go-btn" type="submit" onclick="javascript:goToProperPage();"> Go </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
​$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected');
    if (selected.length) {
        // Do something with your selection
        alert(selected.val());
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/TyLDT/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, which will get the value and will redirect the browser to some other page with id selection passed in the query string.

```
function doSomething()
{
    var seleciton = parseInt($("#my-dropdown").val());

    if(isNaN(selection) || selection <= 0) // Additional verification
    {
        alert("Please select valid option.");
        return;
    }

    window.location.href = 'http://somewhereelse.com/something?id=' + selection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be enough.

```
$(".go-btn").on('click',function(){
             alert($("#my-dropdown").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.go-btn').click(function(){
if($('#my-dropdown').val() == 0 ){
 alert('Please select an option');
return false;

}  
// do what you want here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to get your idea working:

```
var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected').val(); 
// prints the **value** of the option clicked in the dropdown
    
var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected').html(); 
// prints the **text** of the option clicked in the dropdown
```

To invoke when the Dropdown is selected you could either use any of the below:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() { // JQuery Click
    var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected').val();
    console.log(selected); 
});​

// If you prefer not to have a button but need the functionality:
// HTML
<select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown" onchange="getUserValue()">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>
            <option value="1">West</option>
            <option value="2">Land</option>
            <option value="3">Easter</option>
            <option value="4">Springtime</option>
            <option value="5">Celtic</option>
            <option value="6">Spectacular/</option>
            <option value="7">Weekend</option>
            <option value="8">Dark</option>
            <option value="9">Treasures</option>
        </select>

//JQuery
function getUserValue() {
    var selected = $('#my-dropdown option:selected').val();
    alert(selected);
}
```